# Excel Conditional Formatting if cell in Column A AND the cell in Column B are blank than highlight cell in Column G

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to use the conditional formatting in Excel so that
if a cell in Column A is blank and the cell in Column H (of the same row) is also blank then the cell in Column G gets highlighted in blue.

At the moment I am using this formula and it doesn't seem to work.
[Excel_Formula_BlankCellsFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88z83.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule-

```
=AND($A1="",$H1="")
```

[image]